# How to exclude urlArgs from build using r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I use **r.js** optimizer to combine js files based on build profile as it's suggested in [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject). Here's my **build-config.js**:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
    },
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.2013-07-30.js"
})
```

As you can see it's based upon **main.js** file, here's a code of it:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
            'lib/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        ],
    },
});

require([
    'layout',
    'cue',
], function() {

});
```

If I preserve `urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()` in **main.js** all external files (here jquery which is loaded from CDN) look like `.../jquery.js?bust=1377412213`

So it's PITA to comment out this line every time I make a build. I've read through all the documentation and googled for a solution but everything in vain. Maybe I do it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution would work in your case, where you're renaming the main.js file in the r.js build:

```
urlArgs: require.specified('main') ? "bust="+(new Date()).getTime() : null
```

The above snippet will check for the module named 'main', which will match in development, but not in production, where the module is named 'main-built.2013-07-30'.

I've tested in development and production builds and it works! :-)

On the require.specified() function:
[With requirejs is it possible to check if a module is defined without attempting to load it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851541/with-requirejs-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-module-is-defined-without-attempting)

Answer (score 2):

Way late to the party on this, but here the solution I used: append the urlArgs param to the config with a subsequent call.

HTML:

```
<script src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script>require(['main-app']);</script>
```

Config File:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {...},
  shim: {...}
}); 

// Apply the cache bust only for the browser. 
if (window) {
  requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: REQUIRE_NOCACHE ? "bust="+(new Date()).getTime() : null
  });
}
```

The optimizer only takes the first `requirejs.config` declaration and it ignores the subsequent code. The second `requirejs.config` declaration extends rather than overrides the first, so `urlArgs` is still successfully applied to modules in the browser. Hope that helps.

Comment: What is *REQUIRE_NOCACHE*?

Comment: `REQUIRE_NOCACHE` is just a global boolean variable I declare in my dev environments. When it exists, it makes sure that the cache is busted whenever the page is refreshed.

Comment: How do you organize your dev and prod environments?

Comment: That's kind of a broad question... what specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Well, your example doesn't work for me because `r.js` generates result config like `window && urlArgs: bust...` which a browser then perfectly understands and thus adds *bust* to each loaded file. So it's kinda useless. What could work is the parameter **REQUIRE_NOCACHE** which should be `false` during `r.js` work and `true` in dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

As of version `2.2.0`, `urlArgs` now accepts functions.

It sends the `moduleId` and the `url`, so you can segment depending on the path if it should have extra args or not. See https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs